# how to add my root partition to the volume group on a virtual instance

Tags: storage

I Cannot use a live CD here for booting and adding my root file system to the volume group.
output for my df -h command

```
udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           394M  720K  394M   1% /run
/dev/xvda2       25G  961M   23G   5% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvdc1      976M  6.1M  919M   1% /boot
/dev/xvdc2       39G   49M   37G   1% /backup
tmpfs           394M     0  394M   0% /run/user/0
```

output for fdisk -l command

```
Disk /dev/xvdb: 2 GiB, 2147483648 bytes, 4194304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00025cdb

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/xvdb1         63 4192964 4192902   2G 82 Linux swap / Solaris


Disk /dev/xvdh: 64 MiB, 67125248 bytes, 131104 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/xvdc: 40 GiB, 42949672960 bytes, 83886080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xb6b9c5ca

Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/xvdc1         2048  2099199  2097152   1G 83 Linux
/dev/xvdc2      2099200 83886079 81786880  39G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/xvda: 25 GiB, 26843701248 bytes, 52429104 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x4afd158d

Device     Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/xvda1 *      2048   526335   524288  256M 83 Linux
/dev/xvda2      526336 52428799 51902464 24.8G 83 Linux
```

Comment: Please edit the question and explain the problem in more detail. What "virtual instant", Virtual Box, Qemu? How did you get to this point? What have you tried?

Comment: I am using a public cloud and facing the root partition issue that I am trying to solve using logical volumes